# Why is the existing FromJSON instance for (Map String v) not used on (Map String String)?

Tags: haskell, aeson

For this example programm using Aeson:

```
module Main where

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Map as Map
import Data.Functor
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

main = do
  jsonContent <- LBS.readFile "templates/test.json"
  print (decode jsonContent :: Maybe TemplateConfig)

newtype TemplateConfig = TemplateConfig (Map String String)
                         deriving Show

instance FromJSON TemplateConfig where
         parseJSON val = TemplateConfig <$> parseJSON val
```

i get an error complaining about a missing instance:

```
$ ghc test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:17:45:
    No instance for (FromJSON (Map String String))
      arising from a use of `parseJSON'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (FromJSON (Map String String))
    In the second argument of `(<$>)', namely `parseJSON val'
    In the expression: TemplateConfig <$> parseJSON val
    In an equation for `parseJSON':
        parseJSON val = TemplateConfig <$> parseJSON val
```

I understand I need a FromJSON instance to parse JSON and there are also a lot of commonly used instances included in Aeson. According to the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:11) there is an instance `FromJSON v =>  FromJSON (Map String v)` and I thought it should get used in this case.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thats works fine on my system

Comment: Hm. Someone on #haskell also has this code working. I am using aeson-0.6.2.1 on ghc 7.4.2. I guess I will try a clean setup of cabal and check back.

Comment: It's not working for me on GHC 7.6.3 with aeson 0.6.1.0.

Comment: With moving my .cabal and .ghc directories and doing a fresh install of aeson it also works for me now. I still do not see why it did not with my other environment.

Answer (score 1):

There has been an `FromJSON v => FromJSON (Map String v)` instance in [aeson since version 0.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t%3aFromJSON), which was released in February 2011. This was missing in [version 0.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t%3aFromJSON). So I guess you have an old version of aeson installed, which probably got pulled in as a dependency with upper bounds.

Comment: I was using aeson-0.6.2.1. This was one of the first things I checked. It must have been an issue with my cabal environment. After fresh setup it works so I guess something else must have caused it to misbehave.